# Common way to execute a stored proc from both ColdFusion and Railo

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion, railo

I think I've gotten the most simplest scenario built.  I just want to pass it by everyone for a sanity check.  Here's the idea:

GetErrorCodes.cfm does the following:

```
<cfscript>
response = new ErrorCodes().WhereXXX(); // ACF or Railo, doesn't matter
</cfscript>
```

ErrorCodes.cfc:

```
function WhereXXX() {
return new sproc().exec('app.GetErrorCodes'); // All my functions will do this instead of executing the sproc themselves.
}
```

sproc.cfc:

```
component {
function exec(procedure) {
    local.result = {};
    if (server.ColdFusion.productname == 'Railo') {
        return new Railo().exec(arguments.procedure); // Has to be outside of sproc.cfc because ColdFusion throws a syntax error otherwise.
    }
    local.svc = new storedProc();
    local.svc.setProcedure(arguments.procedure);
    local.svc.addProcResult(name='qry'); 
    try {
        local.obj = local.svc.execute();
        local.result.Prefix = local.obj.getPrefix();
        local.result.qry = local.obj.getProcResultSets().qry;
    } catch(any Exception) {
        request.msg = Exception.Detail;
    }
    return local.result;
}
```

Railo.cfc:

```
    component {
        function exec(procedure) {
local.result = {};
            try {
                storedproc procedure=arguments.procedure result="local.result.Prefix" returncode="yes" {
                    procresult name="local.result.qry";
                }
            } catch(any Exception) {
                request.msg = Exception.Message;
            }
            return local.result;
        }
        }
```

So I've been working on this all day, but tell me, is this a sane way to keep the source code the same if it's to be run on either a ColdFusion server or a Railo server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um... just use `<cfstoredproc>` instead of trying to use two different CFScript approaches that are mutually exclusive to each other of the CFML platforms.

Comment: Oh.  I guess I have my head up cfscript so far that I can't look back...  Hmmm.... <cfstoredproc> eh?  I'll have to look into that.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe as part of the installation process, I could have sproc.cfc be either the ACF version, or the Railo version and not have to do an if/then every time a function is called.

Comment: I think you're right. No surprise there.  I need to go back to using tags instead of scripted components - at least for stored procedures.